# Adding External packages other than Nuget on Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, saml-2.0, nuget-package-restore, component-space

I am getting this error -- > **No packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGetOrg**

I am trying to add an External package which is not available in Nuget.org. We are getting this error on the Azure CI/CD pipeline.
**How can I add custom packages on DevOps** Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a nuget feed in your azure devops project.

Please follow the steps given in Microsoft documents to [create nuget feed in azure devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops).

And then publish your custom packages to the nuget feed in your azure devops project.

After your custom packages are published, you need to choose **Feeds to use** and select the nuget feed you created in above step in the **Nuget Restore** task in your pipeline

[image]

You pipeline should be able to find your custom packages now.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. We are going with the same solution.

Comment: Hi @Gaurang That's great. If there is any question please let me know. And if above answer is helpful to you. You can accept it. Thanks

Comment: We have solved this issue with your given solution. because my reputation score is less than 15 so I am unable to vote this answer.